# Filter paths and append text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to set a filter on paths and append text but nothing happens.

```
var filteredElements = svgContainer.selectAll("path")
                //.data(feat.features)
                .append("text")
                .filter(function (d) {
                    if (d.properties.myID > 0) {
                        return true;
                    };
                })

                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return path.centroid(d)[0];
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return path.centroid(d)[1];
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", "2px")
                .text("foo");
```

filteredElements contains 46 elements which are correct but the text is not being appended.

With that code, it works fine but I need the condition in my filter:

```
svgContainer.selectAll("path[PE='1442']")
                .data(feat.features)
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return path.centroid(d)[0];
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return path.centroid(d)[1];
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("font-size", "2px")
                .text("foo");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding this as a second answer because there isn't enough room in a comment, but it suffices as an answer itself.

You have paths drawn on the svg, and you want to draw text for a subset of those paths.

There are two approaches that could be used for this. One is to use a parent `g` element to hold both path and text:

```
// Append a parent:
var g = svg.selectAll(null) // we want to enter an element for each item in the data array
  .data(features)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

// Append the path
 g.append("path") 
  .attr("d",path)  
  .attr("fill", function(d) { ... // etc.

// Append the text to a subset of the features:
g.filter(function(d) {
     return d.properties.myID > 0; // filter based on the datum
  })
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) { .... // etc.
```

The bound data is passed to the children allowing you to filter the parent selection before adding the child text.

The other  approach is closer to what you have done already, but you don't quite have idiomatic d3. We also don't need to re-bind the data to the paths (`d3.selectAll("path").data(`), instead we can use:

```
svgContainer.selectAll(null)
    .data(feat.features.filter(function(d) { return d.properties.myID > 0; }))
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", path.centroid(d)[0])
    .attr("y", path.centroid(d)[1])
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", "2px")
    .text("foo")
```

As an aside,  your initial approach was problematic in that it:

- it appends text to path elements directly, which won't render (as you note)
- it is binding data to the paths again, for each element in the selection, you are binding an item of the data array to a selected element - since the selection is a sub-set of your paths, but your data is the full dataset, you are likely assigning different data to each path (without specifying an identifier, the `i`th item in the full dataset is bound to the `i`th element in the sub-selection).

Answer (score 0):

I have now a solution, I think. My text nodes were inside my path nodes. Now I'm just doing this in my if condition and add my text node under my paths.

```
svgContainer.selectAll("path")
                .data(feat.features)
                .filter(function (d) {
                    if (d.properties.myID > 0) {
                        d3.select("svg")
                            .append("text")
                            .attr("x", path.centroid(d)[0])
                            .attr("y", path.centroid(d)[1])
                            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .attr("font-size", "2px")
                            .text("foo")
                    };
                })
```